# Deploy rails to beanstalk error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying standard rails api app to beanstalk, it was failing with following log :

```
++ export RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3
++ RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3
++ export RUBYOPT=
++ RUBYOPT=
++ export PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
++ PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
+++ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby -
++ eval 'export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby;
export RUBY_VERSION=2.4.3;
export GEM_ROOT="/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0";'
+++ export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
+++ RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
+++ export RUBY_VERSION=2.4.3
+++ RUBY_VERSION=2.4.3
+++ export GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
+++ GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
++ ((  0 != 0  ))
+ cd /var/app/ondeck
+ su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb db:migrate' webapp
`/home/webapp` is not a directory.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/webapp' as your home directory temporarily.
+ '[' false = true ']'
+ su -s /bin/bash -c 'leader_only bundle exec rake db:migrate' webapp
`/home/webapp` is not a directory.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/webapp' as your home directory temporarily.
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rb-readline'.
Gem Load Error is: HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory
```

I am new to Beanstalk, may someone point out what is the issue?
It seems it was trying to use "/home/webapp" but the directory was not created somehow.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer fit your case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935141/336392

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll Thanks for your reference, its the same issue with mine.  However the solution is not clear enough.  I tried setting the HOME=/var/app/ondeck . but still raise the same error message. It seems the variable was not used. And solution no 3 for me is not clear how to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be resolved by deleting rb-readline gem from the build. Not a best fix, but for now it works.